# Android Studio - создание ресурсов

Tags: android, ресурсы, android-studio

В `Android Studio` есть какой-то другой способ создания ресурсов, кроме как только в текстовом редакторе?
Может есть что-то вроде визуального (`GUI`) мастера или окна, где можно указать имя, тип ресурса?

Answer (score 1):

Такая штука есть, насколько знаю, в Eclipse. Так же там присутствует такой инструмент, как ManifestManager, позволяющий визуально( грубо говоря ) редактировать файл манифеста Android приложения. Да и вообще, как-то не верится, что у вас возникли сложности с созданием ресурсов: Drawable ресурсы вообще создаются автоматически( разработчик загружает лишь элементы Drawable ), строки, массивы, стили и прочее создается не менее легче. Вот что касается ресурсов с анимацией, то да, тут уж все не так просто. Но анимацию, как правило, стараются выносить из ресурсов непосредственно в код.

Разработчики Android SDK - люди не глупые. Они сами прекрасно понимают, где легче написать строчку кода( в вашем случае - XML ), а где предпочтительнее использовать визуальный инструмент для упрощения каких-либо действий. Собственно, поэтому в ASDK почти все визуализировано или имеет визуальные тулзы.

Comment: Спасибо. Но у меня был вопрос не по Eclipse.

Comment: Да, да. Это так, к слову.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, если вы имеете ввиду плюхи эклипса, то ресурсы в Android Studio можно редактировать только в ручками :)